# Format string for output dependent on a variable

Tags: formatting, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I would like to have a Fortran write statement formatted to depend on some variable. For example, I could write:

```
write(*,'(3f15.3,3f9.2)') x,y,z,(var(i),i=1,nvari)
```

where `nvari = 3`. But, what if, in some cases, I actually have 4 variables (i.e. `nvari = 4`). I would like to write something like this:

```
write(*,'(3f15.3,nvari(f9.2))') x,y,z,(var(i),i=1,nvari)
```

Now, `nvari` can be anything and the output will work as I like. How can I make something like this work?

Comment: Are `3` and `4` the only choices? Or are you looking for something that can handle any number?

Comment: OP specified 'nvari can be anything'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using Intel fortran, it has a proprietary extension for this -- you can include an existing variable in angle brackets to act as a specifier:

```
  write(*,'(3f15.3,<nvari>f9.2)') x,y,z,(var(i),i=1,nvari)
```

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks for that answer. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: is there a way to do some mathematical operations on the `<nvari>` ?  

eg - `<nvari>+2`, or `3*<nvari>` or `<nvari>**2` in the format statement? i tried with a parentheses .. that did not work!
    
EDIT: the workaround i use now is to define another integer variable `nfmt` and using it instead of `nvari`

Comment: Is there a way to use `A<my_int>` style formatting using the gfortran compiler?

Comment: Please see also other answers if you came looking for a solution, this answer will NOT work in gfortran and some other compilers.

Comment: This helped me realize what the <param> was in a FORMAT statement I had. but now I have to switch compilers :(

Comment: It is **really** unfortunate that this is still the accepted and highest voted answer. This is not legal Fortran at all.

Answer (score 16):

If you compiler supports it, `'(3f15.3, *(f9.2))'`

If you have an older compiler, just use a larger number than you will have items to output, e.g., `'(3f15.3, 999(f9.2))'`.   You don't have to use up the format.

For the most complicated cases you can write a format to a string and use that as your format:

```
write (string, '( "(3f15.3, ", I4, "(f9.2))" )' )  nvari
write (*, string )  x,y,z, (array(i), i=1,nvari)
```

With the understanding of formats, including format reversion, the use of string formats is rarely necessary.

Comment: Cool. Thx. I am using the Intel Fortran Compiler, which I assume is pretty recent. But anyway, it doesn't do the '(3f15.3, *(f9.2))', so I'm using the second solution. BTW, what do you mean by "format reversion"? I did a bit of googling, but didn't come up with much.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of writing the format directly in the write statement, it's also possible to use a character variable.

```
character(len=32) :: my_fmt
my_fmt = '(3f15.3,3f9.2)'
write(*, my_fmt) x, y, z, (var(i), i = 1, nvari)
```

Now it is possible to manipulate the character variable to contain the wanted repeat count before the write statement, using a so-called internal write, or write to internal file.

```
write(my_fmt, '(a, i0, a)') '(3f15.3,', nvari, 'f9.2)'
```

(Just make sure the declared length of `my_fmt` is long enough to contain the entire character string.)

Comment: Or, wrt the last (parenthetical) statement, use an allocatable-lenght character variable.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Sure, if your compiler supports it, that would be the best solution.

Comment: For those using the gfortran compiler, this solution is the recommended solution in the gfortran documentation.  See "Variable FORMAT expressions" in the documentation (section 6.2.3 for gfortran 4, gfortran 5; section 6.2.2 for gfortran 6).

Comment: I caution against writing to strings. Gfortran on Mac is not thread safe for writing to string variables. I/O to files does seem to be thread safe, just not strings.

Answer (score 4):

You wanted to write something like this:

```
write(*,'(3f15.3,nvari(f9.2))') x, y, z, (var(i), i=1,nvari)
```

In fact, there is an old trick in the Fortran standard that allows you to omit the `nvari`, thus:

```
write(*,'(3f15.3,(f9.2))') x, y, z, (var(i), i=1,nvari)
```

or even thus:

```
write(*,'(3f15.3,f9.2)') x, y, z, (var(i), i=1,nvari)
```

The standard says that the last descriptor in the format is implicitly repeated as often as is necessary to accommodate all of the variables in the list.  That 'last descriptor' could be parenthesized such that the last *group* of descriptors is implicitly repeated, for example:

```
write(*,'(3f15.3,(2x,f9.2))') x, y, z, (var(i), i=1,nvari)
```

Comment: I am using `gfortran9`. This didn't work for me unless I used parentheses as in your second example. It also produced the repeated output on new lines rather than on the same line, which is not what the OP wanted.