# Explaining Fortran Write Format

Tags: output, fortran90

I am a beginner of fortran90. Now I am trying to learn fortran code and I am not clear with the description of the write format

> write ( *, '(2x,i4,2x,g14.6,2x,14x,2x,g14.6)' ) 0, unew_norm, error

Can anybody explain to me what does `'(2x,i4,2x,g14.6,2x,14x,2x,g14.6)'` stuff mean.

It would be very nice to teach me the dummy things.

Best

Comment: A quick search yielded **[this](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html)** and **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881186/fortran-output-format-dependent-on-a-variable)**. I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out.

Comment: Thanks for your helping! It is really helpful to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [source](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html):

`nX` means that `n` spaces are added to the line; `iw` means that an integer (hence the `i`) is printed in a field `w` spaces wide; `gw.p` is a specifier for a floating point number (i.e. not an integer) and is a little more complicated. `g` means that we will output in either standard floating point format (i.e. 100.123) or in E format (1.00123E+03), whichever is more compact. `w` means that our number has to fit in a field of width `w`, just like with the integer. The `p` indicates how much precision we want in the output, or the number of digits after the decimal point.

In your case, the format specifier `'(2x,i4,2x,g14.6,2x,14x,2x,g14.6)'` means 2 spaces, integer with width 4, 2 spaces, floating point with width 14 and precision 6, 2 spaces, 14 spaces, 2 spaces, floating point with width 14 and precision 6.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your nice comprehensive sentences! Now I totally understand it!