# Meaning of 3F7.1 in Fortran data format

Tags: fortran, format

I am trying to create an MDM file using HLM 7 Student version, but since I don't have access to SPSS I am trying to import my data using ASCII input. As part of this process I am required to input the data format Fortran style. Try as I might I have not been able to understand this step. Could someone familiar with Fortran (or even better HLM itself) explain to me how this works? Here is my current understanding

```
From the example EG3.DAT they give 

    (A4,1X,3F7.1)

I think

A4 signifies that the ID is 4 characters long.
1X means skip a space.
F.1 means that it should read 1 decimal places.
```

I am very confused about what 3F7 might mean.

EG3.DAT

```
2020   380.0   40.3   12.5
2040   502.0   83.1   18.6
2180   777.0   96.6   44.4
```

Below are examples from the help documents.

[Rules for format statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L02NQ.png)
[Format statement example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zszem.png)

[EG1 data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMp5S.png)
[EG2 data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sybDP.png)
[EG3 data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xWh1.png)

Comment: There are LOTS of questions about Fortran format on this site. It is really good to try to search first. Or look into some documentation or tutorial http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html

Comment: note that HLM is not fortran but is somewhat related. http://www.ssicentral.com/hlm/  I know nothing about it but be aware there could be differences in i/o handling.  In *fortran* it is almost always preferred to not use explicit formatting at all for *input* as list directed input is quite powerful/flexable.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I figured it out after much trial and error and couldn't have done it without all of your help. I will post the full procedure in the Answer in case anyone else needs to convert an Excel document to MDM for HLM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fortran, so-called *data edit descriptors* (which format the input or output of data) may have repeat specifications.

In the format `(A4,1X,3F7.1)` the data edit descriptors are `A4` and `F7.1`.  Only `F7.1` has a repeat specification (the number before the `F`).  This simply means that the format is as though the descriptor appeared repeated: like `F7.1, F7.1, F7.1`.  With a repeat specification of `1`, or not given, there is just the single appearance.

The format of the question, then, is like

```
(A4,1X,F7.1,F7.1,F7.1)
```

This format is one that is covered by the rules provided in one of the images of the question.  In particular, the aspect of repeat specification is given in rule 2 with the corresponding example of rule 3.

Further, in Fortran proper, a repeat count specifier may also be `*` as special case: that's like an exceptionally large repeat count.  `*(F7.1)` would be like `F7.1, F7.1, F7.1, ...`.  I see no indication that this is supported by HLM but if this is needed a very large repeat count may be given instead.

---

In `1X` the `1` isn't a repeat specification but an integral, and necessary, part of the position edit descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

One similar question is [Explaining Fortran Write Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177553/explaining-fortran-write-format/17177886). Unfortunately it does not explicitly treat the F descriptor.

`3F7.1` means 3 floating point numbers, each printed over 7 characters, each with one decimal number behind the decimal point. Leading characters are blanks.

For reading you don't need the `.1` info at all, just read a floating point number from those 7 characters.

You guessed the meaning of A4 (string of four characters) and 1X (one blank) correctly.

Comment: There's a catch with reading and F7.1 - if you don't include a radix point in the input, it will assume the last digit is the fraction. For example, 1234567 read with F7.1 will get you 123456.7. But if you read in 123.456 that's what you'd get. (I'd try to explain the additional effect of the P scale factor edit descriptor, but I'd need another beer or three to do it justice.)

Comment: That's true, but not importsnt here. I ussume tje OP is not using Fortran, just reads the data written by Fortran written using that descriptor and shown above.

Comment: From one of the images I even conclude that in the subset of Fortran rules supported the `.d` component is actually required (greater than zero).

Comment: I don't know, may I am wrong, I don't know HLM, MDM nor SPSS but I assumed the OP is not programming in Fortran.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I figured it out after much trial and error and couldn't have done it without all of your help. I will post the full procedure in the Answer in case anyone else needs to convert an Excel document to MDM for HLM.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure for making MDM file from excel for HLM:

-Make sure ALL the characters in ALL the columns line up

- Select a column, then right click and select Format Cells
- Then click on 'Custom' and go to the 'Type' box and enter the number
  of 0s    you need to line everything up

-Remove all the tabs from the document and replace them with spaces.

- Open the document in word and use find and replace

-To save the document as .dat

- First save it as .txt
- Then open it in Notepad and save it as .dat

To enter the data format (FORTRAN-Style)

The program wants to read the data file space by space, so you have to specify it perfectly so that it reads the whole set properly.
If something is off, even by a single space, then your descriptive stats will be wonky compared to if you check them in another program.

- Enclose the code with brackets ()
- Divide the entries with commas ,

-Need ID column for all levels

- ID column needs to be sorted so that it is in order from smallest to
  largest
- Use A# with # being the number of characters in the ID
- Use an X1 to
  move from the ID to the next column

-Need to say how many characters are needed in each column

- Use F
- After F is the number of characters needed for that column -Use F# (#= number)
- There need to be enough character spaces to provide one 'gap' space
  between each column
- There need to be enough to character spaces to allow for the decimal
- As part of the F you need to specify the number of decimal places
- You do this by adding a decimal point after the F number and then a
  number to represent the spaces you need  -F#.#
- You can use a number in front of the F so as to 'repeat' it. Not
  necessary though. -#F#.#

All in all, it should look something like this:

```
(A4,X1,F4.0,F5.1)
```

Helpful links:

https://books.google.de/books?id=VdmVtz6Wtc0C&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=data+format+fortran+style+hlm&source=bl&ots=kURJ6USN5e&sig=fdtsmTGSKFxn04wkxvRc2Vw1l5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_yPurjYrYAhWIJuwKHa0uCuAQ6AEIPzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false
http://www.ssicentral.com/hlm/help6/error/Problems_creating_MDM_files.pdf
http://www.ssicentral.com/hlm/help7/faq/FAQ_Format_specifications_for_ASCII_data.pdf