# Using parameter in Fortran90 format descriptor

Tags: format, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

How can I use parameters in format descriptor in Fortran90?

I want to make a matrix, say square(n*n), but I want to make it general. So, I declared a parameter like this: `integer,parameter::n=3` (say n is 3 here)

Then after inputting the elements of the matrix in a do/implied do loop, I want to write it with the format function as follows:

`format(ni5)`

But it gives the error: `Unexpected element 'N' in format string`
Any simple way to solve this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fortran: output format dependent on a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881186/fortran-output-format-dependent-on-a-variable)

Comment: I agree with @francescalus.  Note that the accepted answer to that question uses a compiler-specific feature, answers further down the page provide language-standard solutions.

Comment: Yes, this question is tagged [tag:gfortran], but the other [tag:intel-fortran].  Currently only the one answer there is actually specific to ifort.

Comment: Could you say whose answer in that question can be applied here? I'm using gfortran.

Comment: @JohnHamm Any of them except the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Little-known fact: format specifiers can be constructed at runtime as a character string. This means that you can programmatically define the format specifier and pass it to the write statement.

```
CHARACTER(len=30) fm
INTEGER :: i
i = 3
WRITE(fm,'(a,i1,a)')"(",i,"i5)"

WRITE(*,fm)1,2,3
```

In the above, we are generating the actual format specifier with the number of integers that you need to print for the given situation (i), then using that string as the format of the second write statement.

I very rarely see people use this trick, and its possible that it is not defined in the actual standard, but it does work in gfortran.

Comment: *Little-known fact*  Odd assertion to make, two of the answers to the 'duplicate' pointed at by @francescalus use this technique.  There are other instances of its usage in answers here on SO too.

Comment: I just say that because in my experience, it tends to surprise people when they see it for the first time. The read and write statements in fortran have pretty goofy syntax, which I think leads people to assume that they carry more restrictions than they actually do. I consistently see fortran programmers bend over backwards to concoct string-literal formats because they think it's the only way. Even the ifort extension referenced in the duplicates is somewhat indicative that runtime format specification using a character string is uncommon.