# Variable dependent formatting in Fortran90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to understand "variable dependent formatting", specifically where the repeat count in FORTRAN format statement is a variable instead of a fixed number. I have gone through [one of the similar questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881186/format-string-for-output-dependent-on-a-variable), where this is addressed by defining a format variable. I have tried to implement a similar type of test code but I get a run-time error saying "**Fortran runtime error: Missing initial left parenthesis in format**". I am attaching the code that I have. Could you please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thank you

```
program main
implicit none
integer num,i
real,dimension(:),allocatable :: logar
character(len = 100) fmt
print*, "enter any number"
read*,num
allocate(logar(num))
do i = 1,num    
    logar(i) = log(i/3.14)
end do  
open(unit=200,file="num.txt",status="unknown")
write(fmt,'( I4,"(f10.5)" )') num
print*,fmt
write(200,fmt) (logar(i),i=1,num)
end program
```

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of the question you link to, because the answer which talks about doing an internal write to the character variable to be used as the format in the subsequent write correctly shows the use of a leading left parenthesis. If you struggle understanding that answer, please add that context to the question here and we can look at re-opening. (Or someone may disagree that it's a duplicate and re-open regardless.)

Comment: (More specific to this question, you don't need a "variable format" in this case. `write(200,'(*(f10.5))') ...` would suffice without the complication of dynamically creating a format.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
write(fmt,'( I4,"(f10.5)" )') num
```

to

```
write(fmt,'(a, I4,"(f10.5)",a )') '(', num, ')'
```

Else, you are missing the parenthesis in `fmt`. Formats strings are delimited by parentheses.