# format specifiers with no newline and multiple writes in fortran

Tags: format, gfortran

I want to write a header for an output file that's aligned with several variables, something like:

```
var1               var2 ................. varX
value              value                  value
```

So I'd rather avoid manually padding every variable name.
From reading the docs, a format specifier when calling write() is the preferred method.

```
write(1, "(a23)") "var1", "var2", !etc.
```

But this inserts a newline after every variable.
`write(1, "(a23)", advance="no")` does NOT fix this, it only suppresses the newline after the final variable is written.   `write(1, *)` DOES print a newline only after the final variable, but then I lose the spacing.

Tested in GNU Fortran 10.2 with -std=f2003.

Ideas?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

`"(a23)"` is the format for a **single** character variable. When the format finishes, but there are still items to be written in the input list, the format is interpreted from the beginning, but a new line character (end of record) is added.

You have to use a format for multiple items: `"(3a23)"`, `"(3(a23))"`, `"(9999(a23))"` or even `"(*(a23))"`

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881337/721644

Note that you can also use the `t` or `tr` or `x` descriptor to insert padding.