# Using a variable in format string of Fortran and display the values side-by-side

Tags: fortran, variable-length-array, format-string

I understood through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881186/format-string-for-output-dependent-on-a-variable#) on how to use a variable in format string.

`write(*,'(1x,f10.5)')(j(i),i=1,nvar)` seems to work but the values in 'j' are displayed row-wise. I want them to be displayed side-by-side (column-wise) **on the screen and onto a file too**.

I am using, GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39).

**My code:**

```
program test_fmt
implicit none
integer i, nvar
real ::j(2)=(/1.234,5.678/)
nvar=2
write(*,'(f10.5)')(j(i),i=1,nvar)
end
```

**current output:**

1.23400

5.67800

**required output:**
1.23400   5.67800

Might be trivial but I couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions and read the short descriptions of the tags you are adding. Also note that Fortran 90 is very old and not really used any more, or at least not considered by any compiler (they are based on 95 and later standard versions).

Comment: Your format only describes one item. After the format is exhausted, it is interpretted again, but on a new line. Just use a format for multiple items `'(*(f10.5,1x))'`, or for old compilers `'(9999(f10.5,1x))'`. The `1x` is there for a space between the numbers. We have several questions and answers about that, therefore your question will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, regarding the post [you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881186/format-string-for-output-dependent-on-a-variable#) you normally do *not* want to use a variable number in a format string in cases like this. Follow the second answer there and my above comment. Just use a large number like my 9999 or use the * for an unlimited number of repetitions.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir F Героям слава. Using a large number and *, both worked.

Comment: Note you compiler is *very* old, if possible you really should upgrade

Comment: @IanBush I am using that compiler on Oracle virtual box. I am not a tech expert if something goes wrong during upgrade and also awaiting for the present work to be completed. Thank you for the suggestion though. Sure will upgrade.